# Appium Java TestNG Framework>Launch Appium programatically via Mac null point exception with appium main.js file

Tags: java, automation, appium, appium-desktop

Mac book air

Java 1.8

Appium Desktop version 1.8.1

Hi Guys,

I am building a TestNG framework and and I want to start my appium Desktop server programmatically for my tests.  So what I decided to do was to create a java  test class to invoke appium for me, I thought I'd coded it ok but when I ran it just to check. Got a  `'null point exception'`

**1. What did I do wrong?**

**2. How do I fix this?**

Here is the launch appium programmatically code:

```
package aappiumLaunchServer;

import java.io.File;

import io.appium.java_client.service.local.AppiumServiceBuilder;

public class LaunchAppium {

    private static AppiumServiceBuilder service;

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        //text
        stopAppium();
        startAppium();
        stopAppium();
    }

    public static void startAppium() {
        System.out.println("Start Appium Server");
        service = new AppiumServiceBuilder().usingDriverExecutable(new File("/usr/local/bin/node"))
        .withAppiumJS(new File ("/Applications/Appium.app/Contents/Resources/app/node_modules/appium/build/lib/main.js "));
        service.build().start();
        System.out.println("You can now use Appium Server");
    }

    public static void stopAppium(){
        System.out.println("Appium Server is shutting down....");
        try {
            service.build().stop();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
            System.out.println("Your current appium session is terminated... ");
        }
        System.out.println(" Appium Server has shut down. Thank you for using Appium Server");
    }

}
```

Here is the message from eclipse

```
appium Server is shutting down....
java.lang.NullPointerExceptionYour current appium session is terminated... 
 Appium Server has shut down. Thank you for using Appium Server
Start Appium Server

    at aappiumLaunchServer.LaunchAppium.stopAppium(LaunchAppium.java:44)
    at aappiumLaunchServer.LaunchAppium.main(LaunchAppium.java:16)
Exception in thread "main" io.appium.java_client.service.local.InvalidServerInstanceException: Invalid server instance exception has occured: The invalid appium node /Applications/Appium.app/Contents/Resources/app/node_modules/appium/build/lib/main.js  has been defined
    at io.appium.java_client.service.local.AppiumServiceBuilder.validateNodeStructure(AppiumServiceBuilder.java:102)
    at io.appium.java_client.service.local.AppiumServiceBuilder.checkAppiumJS(AppiumServiceBuilder.java:294)
    at io.appium.java_client.service.local.AppiumServiceBuilder.createArgs(AppiumServiceBuilder.java:389)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.service.DriverService$Builder.build(DriverService.java:342)
    at aappiumLaunchServer.LaunchAppium.startAppium(LaunchAppium.java:29)
    at aappiumLaunchServer.LaunchAppium.main(LaunchAppium.java:17)
Caused by: java.io.IOException: The node /Applications/Appium.app/Contents/Resources/app/node_modules/appium/build/lib/main.js doesn't exist
    at io.appium.java_client.service.local.AppiumServiceBuilder.validateNodeStructure(AppiumServiceBuilder.java:104)
    ... 5 more
```

Answer (score 1):

Just with the debug mode at startAppium method try to create a file instance

```
new File ("/Applications/Appium.app/Contents/Resources/app/node_modules/appium/build/lib/main.js "
```

This will probably show you that it can not find the file

Comment: What specifically should I debug? I don't know what I need to debug to fix it.  The file does exist because I was able to locate it and copy it location into terminal which I then copied into the test class.  So I don't know why its saying it can't find it because its exists.

Comment: You can place a breakpoint in your code and stop there to see if you can create a file instance

Comment: Add these lines in beginning of code and check
File file = new File ("/Applications/Appium.app/Contents/Resources/app/node_modules/appium/build/lib/main.js ");

syso(file.getPath()); 
syso(file.getAbsolutePath());
syso(file.getCanonicalPath());

Answer (score 0):

It seems you are trying to use JS main.js file from Appium.app instead install appium using node and you should find your file under
Appium_MAIN_JS = System.getenv(APPIUM_HOME)+"/node_modules/appium/build/lib/main.js" (define APPIUM_HOME in your bash_profile)
It's possible that your code does not have access to reach Appium.app (I presume it is in Application folder)

and then you can call
.buildService(new AppiumServiceBuilder().withAppiumJS(new File(Appium_MAIN_JS)))

Answer (score 0):

If you installed NodeJS from install for Windows and \AppData\Roaming\npm is empty, you should open Windows PowerShell and run command: **npm install -g appium**